# Proving on the equation $(x^2+mx+n)(x^2+px+q)=0$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Find all real numbers k such that if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ and $a>b>c>d \geq k$ then there exist permutations $( m ,n ,p,q)$ of $(a,b,c,d)$ so that the following equation has 4 distinct real solutions :

$(x^2+mx+n)(x^2+px+q)=0$

Here all i did :

$(x^2+mx+n)(x^2+px+q)=0$

$\Leftrightarrow x^2+mx+n=0$ or  $x^2+px+q=0$

so I think the four real solutions, if any, of the equation can only be :

- $ x= \frac{\sqrt{m^2-4n} -m}{2} $
- $ x= \frac{-\sqrt{m^2-4n} -m}{2} $
- $ x= \frac{\sqrt{p^2-4q} -p}{2} $
- $ x= \frac{-\sqrt{p^2-4q} -p}{2} $

So I think to solve the problem we just need to find all real numbers k such that if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ and $a>b>c>d \geq k$ then there exist permutations $( m ,n ,p,q)$ of $(a,b,c,d)$ so that
$p^2 \geq 4q$ and $ m^2 \geq 4n$

We can prove that for $k \geq 4 $ it is absolutely true. So are there any other satisfying $k $ values ? I'm not entirely sure. Hope to get help from everyone. Thanks very much !

Comment: It's not clear to me why you tagged this [tag:ordinary-differential-equations]

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sorry you. I will remove that tag. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: What does "permutations $(m,n,p,q)$ of $(a,b,c,d)$" mean?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I mean the numbers (a,b,c,d) are interchanged to form the tuple (m,n,p,q) , or can also stay in place. Here we only need to show a tuple (m,n,p,q) satisfying . I will be happy if you edit the question for me.

Comment: You found a criteria $m^2\geq 4n$ and $p^2\geq 4q$ to guarantee that all four roots are real.  You also need to find criteria to guarantee that all four roots are distinct.  This removes the inequality from those relationships, but you also need to prove that $\pm\sqrt{m^2-4n}-m\neq\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}-p$

Answer (score 0):

The question needs to be answered in three steps: First, we need to place constraints on $m,n,p,q$ so that all four roots are real.  Second, we need to add constraints so that all four roots are distinct.  Lastly, we need to find $k$ such that for all $a>b>c>d>k$, at least one permutation exists where all the constraints hold true.  Note that by symmetry, permuting $m$ with $p$ and $n$ with $q$ will not change the constraints.

As stated in the post, in order for all four roots to be real, we require $m^2\geq 4n$ and $p^2\geq 4q$.  If equality holds in either constraint, we won't have distinct roots, so our constraints are $m^2>4n$ and $p^2>4q$.  Suppose $k=4-\delta$ for some $\delta>0$. Then, If all four of $m,n,p,q\in(4-\delta,4)$ these constraints cannot hold.  As a result, we require at the very least $k\geq 4$, along with possibly further constraints.

The above constraint guarantees that the two roots defined by $m,n$ are different from each other, and that the two roots defined by $p,q$ are different from each other.  We still need to exclude the remaining pairs of roots.  Let $y,z\in\{-1,1\}$ so that the remaining pair of roots equations can be set up as $\frac{-y\sqrt{m^2-4n}-m}{2}=\frac{-z\sqrt{p^2-4q}-p}{2}$. We will then develop this:
$$-y\sqrt{m^2-4n}-m=-z\sqrt{p^2-4q}-p$$
$$y\sqrt{m^2-4n}+m=z\sqrt{p^2-4q}+p$$
$$y\sqrt{m^2-4n}-z\sqrt{p^2-4q}=p-m$$
$$m^2-4n+p^2-4q-2yz\sqrt{(m^2-4n)(p^2-4q)}=m^2-mp+p^2$$
$$-2yz\sqrt{(m^2-4n)(p^2-4q)}=4n+4q-mp$$
$$4m^2p^2-16m^2q-16np^2+64nq=16n^2+16q^2+m^2p^2+32nq-8mnp-8mpq$$
$$3m^2p^2-16m^2q-16np^2+32nq-16n^2-16q^2+8mnp+8mpq=0$$
$$-16q^2+(-16m^2+32n+8mp)q+(3m^2p^2-16np^2-16n^2+8mnp)=0$$
Let $\beta=\sqrt{m^2-4n}$.  Our quadratic is now (after some algebra): $2q^2+(2\beta^2+4n-mp)q+(-\frac{3}{8}\beta^2p^2+\frac{1}{2}np^2+2n^2-mnp)=0$.  The discriminant is $4\beta^4+16n^2+m^2p^2+16\beta^2n-4\beta^2mp-8mnp+3\beta^2p^2-4np^2-16n^2+8mnp=4\beta^4+16\beta^2n-4\beta^2mp+3\beta^2p^2+m^2p^2-4np^2=4\beta^2(4n-mp)$.  This has no real roots if $mp>4n$, which means that the constraints $mp>4n, mp>4q, m^2>4n, p^2>4q$ are sufficient to guarantee that the roots are real and distinct.  Now, for $k\geq4$, note that the permutations of constraints $4\leq q,n<m,p$ are sufficient to guarantee that each of the four constraints holds true.  As such, 4 is the minimum possible value of k.

Comment: It looks like I miscalculated the discriminant, which is actually $4\beta^2(m^2-mp+p^2)$, which is positive, meaning two real roots. I need to see what constraints are needed to block the roots